# ERC1155 Validation Error code: -32000

Tags: web3.py

I am using web3py to make a transaction. But I am getting validation error:

> {'message': 'VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Need
> operator approval for 3rd party transfers.', 'code': -32000, 'data':
> {'stack': 'RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction:
> revert Need operator approval for 3rd party transfers.\n    at
> Function.RuntimeError.fromResults
> (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/runtimeerror.js:89:13)\n
> at module.exports
> (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/gas/guestimation.js:142:32)',
> 'name': 'RuntimeError'}}

Can someone please help me understand this error? Why is it happening?
I am using function safeTransferFrom (from ERC1155)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we refer to the doc (https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1155.md), we can read in the definition of the `safeTransferFrom` function :

> Caller must be approved to manage the tokens being transferred out of the `_from` account

The user passed to the `_from` parameter of `safeTransferFrom`  has therefore to first approve the caller using `setApprovalForAll(address _operator, bool _approved)` with :

- `_operator` the address of the `safeTransferFrom` caller which can be either an EOA or a smart contract
- `_approved` set to `true`.

To resume:

1. UserA approves UserB/smart contract and authorizes him/it to transfer his funds
2. The approved UserB/smart contract can now transfer the funds of UserA
3. UserA can "disapprove" at any time UserB/smart contract by sending a new `setApprovalForAll` transaction with `_approved` set to false.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to transfer tokens from your own address, make sure you specify your own address as first parameter in `safeTransferFrom`.

If you're trying to send tokens on behalf of a user, the user needs to approve the transaction first, before you can send a transaction through a smart contract with `safeTransferFrom`. To do this, the user needs to call `setApprovalForAll(address _operator, bool _approved)` with the address of the operator (usually a smart contract), and a boolean to indicate if the operator is approved or not.

After that you will be able to transfer tokens on behalf of a user, using `safeTransferFrom`. You cannot call `setApprovalForAll` from a smart contract, for a user. The user needs to explicitly call this function for themselves.